# 'Finally' in penultimate paragraph

Tags: academic-writing, word-choice, essay

I'm writing a **professional** essay for an argument, and I'm trying to find a good paragraph starter to use for the penultimate essay.

I'm leaning towards writing something similar to 'finally,' or 'last but not least,' but I don't think it really fits since it's not the last paragraph. This is the final paragraph where I build my case. The last paragraph, I just restate my main points and leave it there. If it's important, the previous paragraphs two paragraphs were argument ones, and the first paragraph was an intro.

Should I use them, or just scrap them and use something else?

I'm specifically asking if it's fine to use this in a professional setting. If a word somehow existed that means something along the lines of 'last but in a penultimate way', that would be great too.

Comment: If the last paragraph just summarizes all that came before it, then the penultimate paragraph is the last of your argumentation and *finally* or something with a similar meaning seems quite fitting to me, as it will contain the conclusion of your argumentation or the last of your arguments. *Finally* isn't reserved for last paragraphs.

Comment: @Ben it's not to summarise what's come before it, it's to make a new point in my argument.

Comment: Well then you seem to know what you want and don't need other opinions.